# String isn't initialized in Toast (android)

Tags: java, android, string, random, android-toast

```
package com.example.higherorlower;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void ClickFunc(View varView)
    {
        EditText num=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.numID);
        int intNum=Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
        int max=20;
        int min=1;
        int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        String str;
        if(random==intNum)
        {
            str="Correct! Try again!";
        }
        else if(random>intNum)
        {
            str="Lower!";
        }
        else if(random<intNum)
        {
            str="Higher!";
        }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Problem: Variable 'str' might not have been initialized**

I want to try generate random number and play 'guess number' game.But in Toast, it says, str is not initialized! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well. Maybe you as a human know that the `random` variable must match one of the three comparisons. But the compiler does not know. So, the variable `str` might not be initialized (for the compiler). The solution is ... to simply initialize it: `String str = null;`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose or initialise it to a default value that you will see if none of the conditions are met instead of crashing the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to your use-case and think "if I cant show "Correct! Try again!" or "Lower!" or "Higher!", what should I display then?.

```
if(random==intNum)
    {
        str="Correct! Try again!";
    }
    else if(random>intNum)
    {
        str="Lower!";
    }
    else if(random<intNum)
    {
        str="Higher!";
    } else {
         // maybe I can add a default display here?
    }
```

Otherwise, just initialize your `str` to an empty string `""` or `null`

```
String str = "";
```

or

```
String str  = null;
```

However, setting it to `null` is a guaranteed `NullPointerException` if none of those condition blocks is executed, and `NullPointerException` will crash your app.

Specifically, when `Toast` receives a `null` value in its `text` parameter, the system will give you this error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must either set a text or a view
```